# UISearchBar inputAccessoryView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

The `UISearchBar` seems to have the `inputAccessoryView` as a `readOnly` property. How do I set it with my own customToolbar ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit:** As is mentioned in the comments below, this is no longer an issue post iOS 6. See the `UISearchBar` documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchBar/inputAccessoryView).

---

The `UIResponder` (of which `UISearchBar` is an indirect subclass of) [class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder) details a way to accomplish this:

> Subclasses that want to attach custom controls to either a
>   system-supplied input view (such as the keyboard) or a custom input
>   view (one you provide in the inputView property) should redeclare this
>   property as readwrite and use it to manage their custom accessory
>   view. When the receiver subsequently becomes the first responder, the
>   responder infrastructure attaches the view to the appropriate input
>   view before displaying it.

e.x.

```
@interface CustomSearchBar : UISearchBar
@property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputAccessoryView;
@end
```

Comment: this gives a warning `Property 'inputAccessoryView' 'atomic' attribute does not match the property inherited from 'UISearchBar'` any cure for this?

Comment: As of iOS 6.0, `inputAccessoryView` is now `readwrite` and there is no need to create a custom `UISearchBar` subclass.

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 6.0 the inputAccessoryView is now readwrite!

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) UIView *inputAccessoryView;
                      ^^^^^^^^^
```