# Issue with UISearchBar inputAccessoryView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have created an UISearchBar and I have to insert a view in inputAccessoryView but the compiler gives me this error :

> Assignment to readonly property

why this happens ? :

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchbar;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *keyView;

 self.searchbar.inputAccessoryView = keyView;
```

Comment: Don't worry in ios 6 this will be possible

Comment: I need it in iOS 4 and higher ! :-S

Comment: So, subclass is your only option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SearchBars have a UITextView inside, you could look for it in a slightly dirty way and set the inputAccessoryView to it. I'm not sure if this will work, but it's worth a shot

```
UITextField *searchBarField = nil;
for (UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
        searchBarField = (UITextField *)subView;
        searchBarField.inputAccessoryView = ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sneaky. You could also use `[subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]` for a slightly cleaner conditional.

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because this property is readonly, you cannot simply assign a 'UIView'. Read [UISearchBar inputAccessoryView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058133/uisearchbar-inputaccessoryview) for a suggestion how to access this property. You'll have to subclass the searchbar.